# class file to insert data

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, sql, ado.net

I have a insert statement in my aspx.cs which takes like 40 paramters

```
InsertDetailsforBusiness(Profile_Id, C, MID, User_ID, Fullnamee, Gender, Age, Height, complexion, marital_status, Region_or_District, Diet, Profile_Description, Hobbies, WebProfile_Registered_at_FMM_By, dtReg,
           Education, Educational_Degrees, , Education_Medium, Job_Designation, Company_Name, Company_Address, Monthly_Income, Other_Income_Particulars,
       ----------------------------)
```

So can I write a .cs class file to perform this insert?

This is how I started: 
In a class file

```
public string ProfileId { get; set; }
public int CasteId { get; set; }
public int MMBId { get; set; ........
```

But not sure how to proceed in the aspx.cs where the Sp to insert all the paramters is actually called
Thanks
Sun

Answer (score 1):

Use [Parameterized query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx) or [Stored Procedured](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/4278/using-adonet-with-sql-server/3/) instead